# Linux -- How can I run a script after a video has finished playing?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, vlc-media-player, totem

I want to add the default emblem to videos I've finished watching.
Any straightforward, non-manual way to run a script if and exactly if a video has finished playing? Can be for any linux (mint/ubuntu) video player.

Comment: Is that default emblem a fixed image, or an animation? If its a fixed image, you might be able to settle to alter the `not playing` image from vlc-media-player

Comment: No, I meant a caja/nautilus emblem on the video file icon. It really doesn't matter, though. I'd just like to run a shell script when and if the video has finished playing.

Comment: You should use a script that launches the video in your player, and configure the player to auto-close after its finished. Then associate your video with your script. I am not an expert in linux, but I can do it in Windows, so it should be possible to do in linux too I assume.

Comment: But then it would still tag the file as watched even if I closed the player prematurely. I don't know how to distinguish between a user-invoked termination and one caused by the file having finished playing.

Comment: Ah, right. I guess a scripted question: was the watch complete? could do that. Otherwise I don't think its possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
vlc --play-and-exit video.mp4 && echo "Terminated"
```

Substitute `echo "Terminated"` with the actual command you want to run. The `&&` means that if vlc exits with an error code, the command will not be executed. If you want the command to execute even if an error happens,

```
vlc --play-and-exit video.mp4; echo "Terminated"
```

If you supply more files to vlc, then the command will only be executed **once all media has been played**. For example,

```
vlc --play-and-exit s0.mp3 s1.mp4 && shutdown now
```

means the system will shutdown immediately after the two files have been played.

If you want to **perform an action for *each* file played**, you can use this shell script (let's call it `play.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in "$@"; do
    vlc --play-and-exit "$file"
    echo "File $file has been played."
done
```

Then execute it on various files:

```
sh play.sh file1.mp3 'Me & You.mp4' 'file 3.wav'
```

Don't forget to quote the files when appropriate (especially on whitespace and special characters such as `&`, `*`, etc.).

---

The `--play-and-exit` flag is also available for `cvlc`.

Answer (score 0):

Since I asked, I thought I'd share the quick wrapper-based hack I came up with that does it.
I've created the following vlc wrapper and set up video files to open in it rather than vlc directly. It only supports one file at a time. If the thing that moves in vlc as it plays a file goes all the way up to the end, it will run the `tag watched` command at the end if about 60% of the video has been watched.

```
#!/bin/bash
#This depends on the cli interface having been activated in the preferences
# This while loop feeds the `get_length` vlc cli command to cli every 0.1 s
(while :; do echo get_length; sleep 0.1 ; done) | 
#Pass all arguments to vlc and set it up to be fed from the `get_length` while loop
/usr/bin/vlc "$@" |
ruby  -n -e '
    BEGIN { 
    cons_empty=0
    nlines_read=0
  }
    #Strip vlc cli noise
    $_=$_.sub(/^[> ]*/,"")
    #Watch consecutive (cons) empty lines
    if $_.match(/^\s*$/) 
      cons_empty += 1
    else
      #Assume each nonempty stdin line is the duration
      duration = $_.chomp.to_i
      cons_empty = 0
      nlines_read += 1
    end
    #On 10 consecutive empty lines, assume the file has finished playing
    if cons_empty == 10
      time_watched = nlines_read * 0.1
      p time_watched: time_watched, duration: duration
      ret = (time_watched > 0.6 * duration) ? 1 : 0
      exit ret
    end
    ' ||
tag watched "$@" #1 exit means finished watching
```

It's working rather than beautiful code, but it's only a quick fix for an annoyance.

## Dependencies:

bash, ruby, + replace `tag watched` with your actual tagging command.